# How can I stop the transparent area above the navigation bar when pushing my view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Here is a video of what is happening:

https://youtube.com/shorts/Hu4RbQZgcvQ?feature=share

I am using default settings for the navigation bar. I have tried setting background colour for the navigation bar and the navigation controller's view, but this doesn't work.

how can I prevent this?

Comment: Obviously, that's not "standard" behavior, but it's very difficult to see what might be going wrong from that video clip. Start by setting your Simulator `Debug -> Slow Animations`

Comment: https://youtu.be/L8nlhvH9CXI

Comment: Have you set your view background color(s) to `.clear`? or maybe `nil`?